# Optimizing learning rate and number of estimators for multioutput gradient boosting

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I have a dataset with multiple outputs and am trying to use gradient boosting to predict all the values at once. I imported MultiOutputRegressor so multiple outputs can be predicted at once; I'm able to make it work for the default gradient boosting function. However, I'm running into an error when I try to optimize the gradient boosting function for each output.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn import ensemble

params = {'max_depth': 3, 'n_estimators': 100, 'learning_rate': 0.1}
gradient_regressor = MultiOutputRegressor(ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params))
GradBoostModel = gradient_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
prediction_GradBoost = GradBoostModel.predict(X_test)


LR = {'learning_rate':[0.15, 0.125, 0.1, 0.75, 0.05], 'n_estimators':[50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 400]}

tuning = GridSearchCV(estimator = GradBoostModel, param_grid = LR, scoring = 'r2')
tuning.fit(X_train, y_train)
tuning.best_params_, tuning.best_score_
```

I'm trying to use GridSearchCV to cycle through the listed learning rates and number of estimators to find the optimal values. But, I get the following error:

```
Invalid parameter learning_rate for estimator MultiOutputRegressor. 
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`
```

I think I understand the reason for the error: when I try to optimize the gradient boosting parameters, they are passed through the MultiOutputRegressor, which doesn't recognize them. Is this the case? Also, how can I change my code, such that I can optimize these parameters for each output?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the params are prefixed with `estimator__`, in general, to find out what params to use downstream in your pipeline use the `.get_params().keys()` method on your model, eg:

```
print(GradBoostModel.get_params().keys())
dict_keys(['estimator__alpha', 'estimator__ccp_alpha', 'estimator__criterion', 'estimator__init', 'estimator__learning_rate',...
```

Full working example with the linnerud dataset:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import load_linnerud
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
import numpy as np

# Data
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
X, y = load_linnerud(return_X_y=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=rng)

# Model
params = {'max_depth': 3, 'n_estimators': 100, 'learning_rate': 0.1}
gradient_regressor = MultiOutputRegressor(GradientBoostingRegressor(**params))
GradBoostModel = gradient_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
prediction_GradBoost = GradBoostModel.predict(X_test)
LR = {'estimator__learning_rate': [0.15, 0.125, 0.1, 0.75, 0.05], 'estimator__n_estimators': [50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 400]}
print('Params from GradBoostModel', GradBoostModel.get_params().keys())
tuning = GridSearchCV(estimator=GradBoostModel, param_grid=LR, scoring='r2')
tuning.fit(X_train, y_train)
```